# Autoit Aerender case between 2 variants

Tags: after-effects

Using aerender and autoit I convert a project to an .avi file.

To accomplish this I use following (in the command line):

```
Send('aerender -project C:\Projects\app.aep -comp "Main" -output C:\Projects\output\test.avi' & "{ENTER}")
```

The problem is now that I have 2 variants of images "folder".

One has 10 images and the other one has 20 images.

How can I use aerender to create seperate folder with those numbers of images.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. The AerenderMakeImage function takes two parameters. The new folder you want to put the image in and the name of the new image.

```
AerenderMakeImage("C:\Projects\new_output\", "test.avi")

Func AerenderMakeImage($sImgFolderPath, $sNewImageName)

    ;makes image path if there is not one
    If FileExists($sImgFolderPath) = 0 Then DirCreate($sImgFolderPath)

    $sRuncmd = 'aerender -project C:\Projects\app.aep -comp "Main" -output '& $sImgFolderPath & $sNewImageName

    ;uses run instead of send because it is a more stable solution the Send
    Run(@ComSpec & " /c " & $sRuncmd, @ScriptDir, @SW_HIDE)

    ;Run(@ComSpec & " /c " & $sRuncmd, @ScriptDir, @SW_SHOW) ;Use this if you want to see the CMD

EndFunc   ;==>AerenderMakeImage
```